# Convex Polygon - Splitting into Two Congruent Pieces

Tags: convex-geometry

Dear All,

I have **convex polygon** (expressed by points in **cartesian coordinate system**). I am looking for a solution to splitting into two congruent pieces. Is there any way to to estimate the points that lead cut?

Comment: I cannot parse the question: what do you mean by splitting? what do you mean by "estimate the points that lead cut"?

Comment: @Igor: My take is that "splitting" means to find a boundary-to-boundary path that "cuts" the polygon into two congruent pieces.

Answer (score 6):

There exist convex quadrilaterals which have no such splitting.
And there is an $O(n^3)$ algorithm to decide if such a splitting exists for a (nonconvex) $n$-gon.
See the paper by
Dania El-Khechen, Thomas Fevens, John Iacono, and Günter Rote,
"Partitioning a polygon into two mirror congruent pieces."
In *Proc. 20th Canad. Conf. Comput. Geom.*, pages 131-134, August 2008
([PDF download link](http://cccg.ca/proceedings/2008/paper32full.pdf)).

               
[image: Fig 1]
I am unaware of work specifically on convex polygon partitions, but perhaps if you
specialize the algorithm in this paper to that simpler situation, its time complexity will
improve.